Provide / Inject value not getting updated if its reactive value is changed - VueJS
I am quite new to Vue.js coming from a React background. I have a reactive variable config which is passed to provide() function in a component and used by other component using inject(). But the the value in provide is not getting updated once reactive variable is updated.
Component A
<script setup>
const localState = reactive({
  resellingAmount: null,
})

const salesPrice = computed(() => localState.resellingAmount)

const config = reactive({
  amount: salesPrice.value,
})

provide('config', config)

onMounted(async () => {
  const response = await ListingService.getLocationResellingConfiguration(location.value.id)
  localState.resellingAmount = response.data.amount
  window.addEventListener('resize', reloadOnResize)
})
</script>
<template>
...
</template>

Component B
<script setup>
const store: object = inject('store')
</script>

<template>
  <div><h1>{{ config.amount }}</h1></div>
</template>


Expected Behaviour - Component B should display new value of amount
Actual Behaviour - Component B is still displaying old value of amount

The difference with React's reactivity is that the state is assigned once on component setup and not on each render. Accessing a value like amount: salesPrice.value there is the same as amount: null, amount can't be reactive this way.
It should be:
const config = reactive({
  amount: salesPrice,
})

This results in config.amount readonly property that reacts to salesPrice.value changes.

Thanks for the quick reply. I have tried that too. It doesn't update and it's weird reactivity behavior. Does provide() maintain the reactivity?

Can you provide a way to reproduce, e.g. play.vuejs.org ? It should work with the fix. provide() passes a value as is and doesn't affect reactivity
